# Stenciljs PWA Favicon

Tags: ionic-framework, favicon, stenciljs

How can I change the Favicon of a Stencil PWA ?
I've changed the `favicon.ico` file inside `src/assets/icon` and done `npm run build`

Inside `www/assets/icon` all the files, also `favicon.ico` has change correctly, but when I check my pwa with `npm start`, the favicon it's the older one.

I don't get how to change it. Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: It might be cached. Have you tried it in another browser?

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the cache and changed browser :S

Comment: Is the `www/favicon.ico` correct? If yes, check with browser DevTools where the favicon is actually loaded from.